# executenonquery en C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, .net

Saludos, quisiera saber que valor que me devuelve executenonquery en caso de que no me afecte ningún campo, ejemplo

```
        string respuesta = "";
        SqlConnection SqlConexion = new SqlConnection();
        try
        {
            SqlConexion.ConnectionString = Conexion.ConexionPalmComSync;
            SqlConexion.Open();
            SqlCommand SqlComando = new SqlCommand();
            SqlComando.Connection = SqlConexion;
            SqlComando.CommandText = "SP_INGRESAR_CONDUCE";
            SqlComando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter ParDate = new SqlParameter();
            ParDate.ParameterName = "@date";
            ParDate.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
            ParDate.Value = Conduce.Date;
            SqlComando.Parameters.Add(ParDate);

            SqlParameter ParVendedor = new SqlParameter();
            ParVendedor.ParameterName = "@vendedor";
            ParVendedor.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar;
            ParVendedor.Size = 10;
            ParVendedor.Value = Conduce.Vendedor;
            SqlComando.Parameters.Add(ParVendedor);

            respuesta = SqlComando.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0 ? "Ya existe en el sistema" : "OK";

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            respuesta = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (SqlConexion.State == ConnectionState.Open) SqlConexion.Close();
        }
        return respuesta;
```

quiero saber que valor me devuelve en caso de que no me afecte ninguna fila

Este es el procedimiento almacenado creo que es el procedimiento

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_INGRESAR_CONDUCE]
@date datetime,
@vendedor varchar(10)
AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT OFF;

```
    DECLARE @PALMID VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @TRANSNUM VARCHAR(16)
    DECLARE @CODPROD VARCHAR(16)
    DECLARE @DESCRIP VARCHAR(45)
    DECLARE @CANTIDAD INT
    DECLARE @ALMORIGEN VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @ALMDESTIONO VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @FECTRANS DATETIME
    DECLARE @IDVENDEDOR VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @IDAYUDANTE VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @IDAYUDANTE2 VARCHAR(10)
    DECLARE @TIPODOCUMENTO VARCHAR(14)
    DECLARE @CODRUTA VARCHAR(14)
    DECLARE @RECIBIDOEN DATETIME
    DECLARE @IPADDRESS VARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @PROCESADO INT
    DECLARE @ROWID INT
    DECLARE @COD VARCHAR(16)
    DECLARE @VENDEDOR_DEVOLUCION VARCHAR(10)

    DECLARE CUR_INGRESAR_CONDUCE CURSOR
    FOR SELECT * FROM IN_TRANSINV WHERE FECTRANS = @date and IDVENDEDOR = @vendedor

    OPEN CUR_INGRESAR_CONDUCE
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_INGRESAR_CONDUCE INTO @PALMID, @TRANSNUM, @CODPROD, @DESCRIP,
    @CANTIDAD, @ALMORIGEN, @ALMDESTIONO, @FECTRANS, @IDVENDEDOR, @IDAYUDANTE, @IDAYUDANTE2,
    @TIPODOCUMENTO, @CODRUTA, @RECIBIDOEN, @IPADDRESS, @PROCESADO, @ROWID

    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN
                SET @COD = DBO.FT_COD_DEVOLUCION('D0000000')
                SET @VENDEDOR_DEVOLUCION = (SELECT IDVENDEDOR from OUT_CONFIG where PALMID = @PALMID)

                IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SITGPIntegration.DBO.RelacionConduce
                                      WHERE TipoDocumento = 'Conduce' and NoDocumento = @TRANSNUM)
                    BEGIN
                        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ORDDOCID FROM GPHN.DBO.SVC00700 WHERE ORDDOCID = @TRANSNUM)
                            BEGIN
                                EXEC SP_INSERTAR_CABECERA @TRANSNUM,'','','',1,@FECTRANS,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000','','','','','','','',@ALMORIGEN,'',@ALMDESTIONO,306130.00000,0,'','','','sa'
                            END
                        ELSE
                            BEGIN
                                EXEC SP_INSERTAR_ERROR_CABEZA  @ALMORIGEN,@TRANSNUM,'Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint ''PKSVC00700''. Cannot insert duplicate key in object ''dbo.SVC00700''.  The statement has been terminated.',@FECTRANS
                            END
                        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ORDDOCID FROM GPHN.DBO.SVC00701 WHERE ORDDOCID = @TRANSNUM)
                            BEGIN                       
                                EXEC SP_INSERTAR_DETALLE  @TRANSNUM,16384,1,@CODPROD,@DESCRIP,'1X1UND',@CANTIDAD,@CANTIDAD,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'',0,0,'',0,'',0,@ALMORIGEN,'',@ALMDESTIONO,1,1,0,0,''
                            END
                        EXEC SP_INSERTAR_CONDUCE @TRANSNUM,'Conduce',@IDVENDEDOR,@CODRUTA,@FECTRANS,@IDAYUDANTE,@IDAYUDANTE2,'sa',''                        

                        /*DEVOLUCION*/

                        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ORDDOCID FROM GPHN.DBO.SVC00700 WHERE ORDDOCID = @COD)
                            BEGIN
                                EXEC SP_INSERTAR_CABECERA @COD ,'','','',1,@FECTRANS,'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000','','','','','','','',@ALMORIGEN,'','SAN ISIDRO',306130.00000,0,'','','','sa'
                            END

                        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ORDDOCID FROM GPHN.DBO.SVC00701 WHERE ORDDOCID = @COD)
                            BEGIN
                                EXEC SP_INSERTAR_DETALLE  @COD,16384,1,@CODPROD,@DESCRIP,'1X1UND',@CANTIDAD,@CANTIDAD,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'',0,0,'',0,'',0,@ALMORIGEN,'','SAN ISIDRO',1,1,0,0,''
                            END 
                        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT NoDocumento FROM SITGPIntegration.dbo.RelacionConduce WHERE NoDocumento = @COD)
                            BEGIN
                                EXEC SP_INSERTAR_CONDUCE  @COD,'Devolucion',@VENDEDOR_DEVOLUCION,@CODRUTA,@FECTRANS,@IDAYUDANTE,@IDAYUDANTE2,'sa',''                        
                            END
                        FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_INGRESAR_CONDUCE INTO @PALMID, @TRANSNUM, @CODPROD, @DESCRIP,
                        @CANTIDAD, @ALMORIGEN, @ALMDESTIONO, @FECTRANS, @IDVENDEDOR, @IDAYUDANTE, @IDAYUDANTE2,
                        @TIPODOCUMENTO, @CODRUTA, @RECIBIDOEN, @IPADDRESS, @PROCESADO, @ROWID
                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        BREAK
                    END
        END
        CLOSE CUR_INGRESAR_CONDUCE
        DEALLOCATE CUR_INGRESAR_CONDUCE
END
```

GO

Comment: a qué te refieres con "qué valor devuelve"?

Comment: por ejemplo si tengo un insert y no me lo ejecuta porque ya existe, porque tengo esa validación eso es lo que quiero saber que valor tiene si no se ejecuta

Comment: `SET NOCOUNT OFF` no tiene nada que ver con insertar valores que ya existen en una tabla....

Comment: amigo, lo que pasa es lo siguiente tengo un procedimiento almacenado con un cursor el cursor me devuelve x registros insertados como estoy comparando en una variable string no voy a poder comparar si es mayor a 1, quiero saber si tiene valer negativo cuando no se ejecute para entonces evaluar esa condición

Comment: respuesta = SqlComando.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0 ? "Ya existe en el sistema" : "OK";

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                respuesta = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (SqlConexion.State == ConnectionState.Open) SqlConexion.Close();
            }
            return respuesta;
ejemplo tengo este condigo cuando ejecute el executenonquery() si no me afecto nada que me devuelva ya no existe

Comment: @Ing.JoseValera Pero entonces esto no es SQL Server solo, es C#, tu pregunta está mal planteada y falta información

Comment: Ok, Disculpa La Formulare de nuevo

Comment: Pero en dado caso no me puedes ayudar con eso lo que pasa es que estoy usando la libreria de sql y quiero saber que me devuelve el exacute non query,

Comment: @Ing.JoseValera Tienes que poner el código que estás ejecutando y mostrarnos las pruebas que hayas hecho para poder ayudarte con ése código.

Comment: Bien ese es el código lo que quiero hacer es por si no me afecta ninguna fila, que me devuelva ya no existe, agradecería la ayuda

Comment: Es un procedimiento con un cursor, funciona totalmente bien es aquí donde tengo el inconveniente porque lo probé en sql server y funciona bien, lo que necesito saber es si ejecuta el procedimiento y no afecta ninguna columna

Comment: @Ing.JoseValera Pero necesitamos saber que tiene ese procedimiento almacenado, deberias ponerlo tambien

Answer (score 2):

> quisiera saber que valor que me devuelve executenonquery en caso de que no me afecte ningún campo

Como indica la página [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx), `ExecuteNonQuery` devuelve la cantidad de registros afectados si la sentencia ejecutada es un `INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE`.  En el caso de todo otro tipo de sentencia, te devuelve `-1`.

De acuerdo con eso, siendo que lo que ejecutas es un procedimiento almacenado, siempre te devolverá `-1`, que haya afectado registros o no.

Comment: Pero en este caso no me esta afectando ningún registro y me devuelve ok, lo cual no debería porque no se a afectado ningún registro

Comment: `SqlComando.ExecuteNonQuery() == 0 ? "Ya existe en el sistema" : "OK"` siempre va a resultar en `"OK"` si el valor devuelto es `-1` como te indiqué en la respuesta. Esa es tu lógica, no la mía. Basicamente, el valor devuelto por `ExecuteNonQuery()` es inútil en tu caso. No puedes usarlo para determinar la cantidad de registros afectados ya que siempre devolverá -1.

Comment: Pero en esa misma linea de código lo que hice fue si es igual a 0 osea que no se ha afectado ningún registro ya no existe si es otro numero existe porque por lo menos me afecto uno, creo que es así, si estoy en lo correcto

Comment: Este es mi último comentario sobre esto, porque ya el asunto está más que claro.  En tu caso, `SqlComando.ExecuteNonQuery()` SIEMPRE devolverá -1. Esa es la forma como funciona con procedimientos almacenados. Si insistes en tratar de interpretar ese valor para determinar si algo existe o no, vas en mal camino.

Comment: OK, lo entendi perfectamente, lo que evaluo es -1 y ese sera el resultado de el procedimiento almacenado

Comment: Ah, y gracias lo que tu pensabas que era imposible y que voy en mal camino ya lo hice gracias por la ayuda.. el vencedor no es siempre quien gana, si no el que nunca se rinde..!!

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres saber el mensaje de respuesta una de las opciones es con una variable output:

c#:

```
string msg = string.empty;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(micadena, sqlConn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@miparametro", id);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@msg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output; 

int res = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()); 
msg = cmd.Parameters["@MSG"].Value.ToString(); //aqui obtienes el msg devuelto
```

sql:

```
,@miparametro int
,@msg As Varchar(300) OUTPUT

--un poco de sql por aqui... bla bla...
SET @msg = 'tu mensaje personalizado desde la query'
```

en sintesis (en tu codigo):

```
msg = 'tu mensaje personalizado desde la query'
```

Comment: Gracias me por tu ayuda pero hace tiempo que lo solucione, muchas gracias